# what does ${MYPATH//://bin:}/bin mean in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, path

I've been seeing a case of appending a particular dir named 'bin' under `$MYPATH` (which could contain multiple values in format of `a:b:c`) to `$PATH`, the solution is `${MYPATH//://bin:}/bin` ,for example:

```
> MYPATH=/local/a:/local/b
> echo ${MYPATH//://bin:}/bin
/local/a/bin:/local/b/bin
> echo ${MYPATH}/bin  # as a bad example, this is not what we want
/local/a:/local/b/bin
```

as you see, `${MYPATH//://bin:}/bin` works pretty well.

My question is where is such parameter expansion documented, I can't find any doc(include 'man bash', seems it's not the "Substring  Expansion" which in format of `{parameter:offset:length}`) on explaining the syntax.

Could anyone explain it to me or point me the doc of this feature?

Comment: Shell parameter expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Comment: seems it's "Substring Expansion" indeed, still trying to figure out how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Parameter expansion. In this case, it replaces all `:` with `/bin:`

```
${MYPATH//://bin:}
  ^^^^^^  ^ 
   |    ^^| ^^^^^
   |    | | replacement
   |    | match string
   var  match all
```

Too many slashes are misleading. See better examples:

```
MYPATH="hello1hello2"
$ echo ${MYPATH//hello/bye}
bye1bye2
```

or:

```
d="a:b:c"
$ echo ${d//://bin:}
a/bin:b/bin:c
```

Note the difference if we just use one slash:

```
$ echo ${MYPATH/hello/bye}
bye1hello2
```

More info in [Parameter expansion#Search and replace](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Answer (score 1):

### Substring Expansion

This is a confusing, although valid, implementation of the [substring expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) form of:

```
${parameter//pattern/string}
```

The doubled forward slash will replace all copies of *pattern* of with *string*, rather than just the first match. In your example:

```
echo ${MYPATH//://bin:}/bin
```

the expansion says:

1. Match *all* copies of pattern `:`.
2. Replace each match with the string `/bin:`.
3. Append a literal `/bin` to the result of the substring expansion, since it's outside the parameter expansion.

Comment: I hope I can accept both of the answers from you and fedorqui, but can't :(, thanks for your explain on this.